# Negation rule, proof.$\neg[\forall x, \forall y, p(x,y)]=[\exists x,\exists y, \neg p(x,y)]$

Tags: logic, first-order-logic

$$\neg[\forall x, \forall y, p(x,y)]=[\exists x,\exists y, \neg p(x,y)]$$

I have doing some set proofs in Munkres Topology, and wanted to know deeply about proofs. I end up with logical symbols, propositions but I stuck at this, how do we do proof of above equivalence? I have no clue to start with.

Comment: One common definition of $\exists$ is simply $\neg \forall \neg$. So this is simply double negation elimination. (There are other definitions/axiomatizations.)

Answer (score 2):

Well, the basis to understand such assertions is

$\neg \forall x: p(x) $ is equivalent to $\exists x: \neg p(x)$.

From here, you get

$\neg \forall x:\forall y: p(x,y)
\Longleftrightarrow \exists x:\neg\forall y: p(x,y) 
\Longleftrightarrow \exists x:\exists y: \neg p(x,y)$.